# pandas conditions across rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Is there a better way to accomplish this?  The function determines the `Category` for each row based on some conditions.  Another set of conditions determines the `ChangeGroup` for the row.  Not all the conditions are written but it more or less gets the point across.  The determination for a `ChangeGroup` is made based on a previous row where `ChangeGroup == 'BECMG'`.

### Data:

```
MOCK_DATA = [{'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 12:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 13:00:00', 'WindDirection': 200, 'WindSpeed': 7, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510111', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.09, 'Temperature': -2}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 13:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 14:00:00', 'WindDirection': 200, 'WindSpeed': 8, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510111', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.08, 'Temperature': -1}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 14:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 15:00:00', 'WindDirection': 210, 'WindSpeed': 10, 'WindGust': 15, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510111', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.06, 'Temperature': 0}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 15:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 16:00:00', 'WindDirection': 220, 'WindSpeed': 11, 'WindGust': 20, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520111', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.02, 'Temperature': 2}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 16:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 17:00:00', 'WindDirection': 230, 'WindSpeed': 11, 'WindGust': 20, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 15500.0, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520113', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.01, 'Temperature': 4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 17:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 18:00:00', 'WindDirection': 260, 'WindSpeed': 10, 'WindGust': 23, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SCT', 'CloudBase1': 4500.0, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 6000.0, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510111', 'Icing': '620540', 'Altimeter': 30.01, 'Temperature': 6}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 18:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 19:00:00', 'WindDirection': 290, 'WindSpeed': 15, 'WindGust': 38, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 5000.0, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 7500.0, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510118', 'Icing': '620621', 'Altimeter': 29.99, 'Temperature': 7}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 19:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 20:00:00', 'WindDirection': 290, 'WindSpeed': 18, 'WindGust': 39, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SCT', 'CloudBase1': 6000.0, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 8500.0, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520118', 'Icing': '620700', 'Altimeter': 30.0, 'Temperature': 7}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 20:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 21:00:00', 'WindDirection': 300, 'WindSpeed': 20, 'WindGust': 42, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520111', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.06, 'Temperature': 5}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 21:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 22:00:00', 'WindDirection': 310, 'WindSpeed': 18, 'WindGust': 40, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 6500.0, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520128', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.13, 'Temperature': 3}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 22:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-19 23:00:00', 'WindDirection': 310, 'WindSpeed': 17, 'WindGust': 39, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520128', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.18, 'Temperature': 1}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-19 23:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 00:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 15, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520121', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.24, 'Temperature': 0}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 00:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 01:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510130', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.3, 'Temperature': -1}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 01:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 02:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '520131', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.34, 'Temperature': -2}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 02:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 03:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510130', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.38, 'Temperature': -3}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 03:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 04:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 11, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False,'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.4, 'Temperature': -3}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 04:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 05:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 9, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.42, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 05:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 06:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 7, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.44, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 06:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 07:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 6, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.45, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 07:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 08:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 6, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.46, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 08:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 09:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 5, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510140', 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.45, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 09:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 10:00:00', 'WindDirection': 320, 'WindSpeed': 4, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.45, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 10:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 11:00:00', 'WindDirection': 310, 'WindSpeed': 2, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.46, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 11:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 12:00:00', 'WindDirection': 280, 'WindSpeed': 1, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.48, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 12:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 13:00:00', 'WindDirection': 170, 'WindSpeed': 1, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.49, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 13:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 14:00:00', 'WindDirection': 130, 'WindSpeed': 2, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.5, 'Temperature': -4}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 14:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 15:00:00', 'WindDirection': 110, 'WindSpeed': 3, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.5, 'Temperature': -3}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 15:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 16:00:00', 'WindDirection': 170, 'WindSpeed': 2, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.52, 'Temperature': -2}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 16:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 17:00:00', 'WindDirection': 200, 'WindSpeed': 5, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.51, 'Temperature': 0}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 17:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 18:00:00', 'WindDirection': 200, 'WindSpeed': 7, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.49, 'Temperature': 1}, {'ChangeGroup': None, 'Category': None, 'Beginning': '2022-02-20 18:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-20 19:00:00', 'WindDirection': 190, 'WindSpeed': 8, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SKC', 'CloudBase1': None, 'CloudCover2': None, 'CloudBase2': None, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': None, 'Altimeter': 30.44, 'Temperature': 2}]
```

### Data2

Another data with more changes to `Category` due to cloud cover.  Sorry I'm working in slightly different environments.  This set does not have the `ChangeGroup` and `Category` included

```
MOCK_DATA2 = [{'Beginning': '2022-02-03 06:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 07:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 1500, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 2100, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '600197', 'Altimeter': 30.25, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 07:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 08:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.26, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 08:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 09:00:00', 'WindDirection': 0, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.27, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 09:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 10:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.25, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 10:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 11:00:00', 'WindDirection': 0, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.25, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 11:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 12:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.25, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 12:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 13:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 13:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 14:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 14:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 15:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 15:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 16:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650138', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 16:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 17:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 1500, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 2200, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.27, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 17:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 18:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2200.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.26, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 18:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 19:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.24, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 19:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 20:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 15, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1400, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510121', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.22, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 20:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 21:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 15, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1400, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510121', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.21, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 21:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 22:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1400, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510121', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.22, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 22:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-03 23:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1400, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.23, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-03 23:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 00:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 14, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '650197', 'Altimeter': 30.24, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 00:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 01:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2100.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '620197', 'Altimeter': 30.26, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 01:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 02:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 13, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2200.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '620197', 'Altimeter': 30.27, 'Temperature': -5}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 02:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 03:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': '-SN', 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2200.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '620197', 'Altimeter': 30.27, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 03:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 04:00:00', 'WindDirection': 20, 'WindSpeed': 12, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 1500, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 2200, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': '510131', 'Icing': '620207', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 04:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 05:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 11, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 1500, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 2200, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620207', 'Altimeter': 30.29, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 05:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 06:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 11, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2200.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620207', 'Altimeter': 30.29, 'Temperature': -6}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 06:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 07:00:00', 'WindDirection': 10, 'WindSpeed': 10, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'FEW', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'BKN', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'OVC', 'CloudBase3': 2200.0, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620207', 'Altimeter': 30.28, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 07:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 08:00:00', 'WindDirection': 0, 'WindSpeed': 9, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SCT', 'CloudBase1': 800, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620207', 'Altimeter': 30.29, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 08:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 09:00:00', 'WindDirection': 350, 'WindSpeed': 10, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 900, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620138', 'Altimeter': 30.31, 'Temperature': -7}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 09:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 10:00:00', 'WindDirection': 350, 'WindSpeed': 10, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 900, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620138', 'Altimeter': 30.32, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 10:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 11:00:00', 'WindDirection': 350, 'WindSpeed': 9, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 900, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620138', 'Altimeter': 30.33, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 11:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 12:00:00', 'WindDirection': 340, 'WindSpeed': 8, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'BKN', 'CloudBase1': 900, 'CloudCover2': 'OVC', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': None, 'CloudBase3': None, 'CloudCover4': None, 'CloudBase4': None, 'CloudCover5': None, 'CloudBase5': None, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620138', 'Altimeter': 30.35, 'Temperature': -8}, {'Beginning': '2022-02-04 12:00:00', 'Ending': '2022-02-04 13:00:00', 'WindDirection': 350, 'WindSpeed': 8, 'WindGust': None, 'Visibility': 9999, 'Precipitation': None, 'Obscuration': None, 'Other': None, 'TSFlag': False, 'CloudCover1': 'SCT', 'CloudBase1': 900, 'CloudCover2': 'SCT', 'CloudBase2': 1500, 'CloudCover3': 'BKN', 'CloudBase3': 2900.0, 'CloudCover4': 'BKN', 'CloudBase4': 6500.0, 'CloudCover5': 'OVC', 'CloudBase5': 9000.0, 'WSHeight': None, 'WSDirection': None, 'WSSpeed': None, 'Turbulence': None, 'Icing': '620801', 'Altimeter': 30.35, 'Temperature': -9}]
```

### Edit 1:

I've started to move some of the conditions out of the for loop and into more vectorized / list comprehension solutions

```py
def dev_mock(taf: pd.DataFrame):
    """\
    applies the ammendment & specification criteria
    """
    ...
    taf.loc[0, 'ChangeGroup'] = 'BECMG'

    taf['MaxWind'] = taf[['WindSpeed', 'WindGust']].max(axis=1)

    cover, bases = taf[pd.Index(CLOUD_COVER)], taf[pd.Index(CLOUD_BASE)]

    cover = ((cover == 'BKN') | (cover == 'OVC'))

    cover.columns = bases.columns

    taf['MinCig'] = bases[cover].min(axis=1)

    taf['Category'] = [criteria.loc[
        (cig >= criteria['ceiling']) & (vis >= criteria['visibility'])
    ].index.max() for cig, vis in zip(taf.MinCig, taf.Visibility)]

   ...
```

### Edit 2:

My attempt to implement the <s>`itertools.accumulate`</s>  `functools.reduce` function. In the first instance I generate a new `DataFrame` as the accumulator from rows 0 & 1 and return that `DataFrame` as the `accumulator`.

```py
    ...

    def accumulator_funk(acc, row) -> pd.DataFrame:

        if not isinstance(acc, pd.DataFrame):  # first instance

            df = pd.DataFrame(
                [acc, row]).set_index('Index')

            df.loc[row.Index, 'ChangeGroup'] = 'BECMG' if acc.Category != row.Category else None

            return df

        acc.loc[row.Index, 'Category'] = row.Category

        predom = acc.loc[acc.ChangeGroup == 'BECMG'].iloc[-1]

        acc.loc[row.Index, 'ChangeGroup'] = (
            'BECMG' if predom.Category != row.Category else None)

        return acc

    # dfs = itertools.accumulate(
    #    taf[['Category', 'ChangeGroup']].itertuples(), accumulator_funk)

    # fcst = ([df for df in dfs][-1])
    # more appropriate solution
    fcst = functools.reduce(
        accumulator_funk, taf[['Category', 'ChangeGroup']].itertuples())
    print(fcst)
```

### Out: MOCK_DATA2

```
      Category ChangeGroup
Index                     
0            D       BECMG
1            C       BECMG
2            C        None
3            C        None
4            C        None
5            C        None
6            C        None
7            C        None
8            C        None
9            C        None
10           D       BECMG
11           D        None
12           D        None
13           D        None
14           D        None
15           D        None
16           D        None
17           D        None
18           D        None
19           D        None
20           D        None
21           D        None
22           D        None
23           D        None
24           D        None
25           D        None
26           C       BECMG
27           C        None
28           C        None
29           C        None
30           E       BECMG
```

### Original Solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
CRITERIA = {
    'ceiling': [2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100],
    'visibility': [4800, 3200, 3200, 1600, 800],
    'index': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
}
CLOUD_COVER = (
    'CloudCover1',
    'CloudCover2',
    'CloudCover3',
    'CloudCover4',
    'CloudCover5'
)
CLOUD_BASE = (
    'CloudBase1',
    'CloudBase2',
    'CloudBase3',
    'CloudBase4',
    'CloudBase5'
)
CLOUD_GROUP = np.stack((CLOUD_COVER, CLOUD_BASE), axis=1).flatten()

def dev_mock(taf: pd.DataFrame):
    """\
    applies the ammendment & specification criteria
    """

    criteria = pd.DataFrame(CRITERIA).set_index(
        'index').rename_axis('Category')

    def lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height(taf_row: pd.Series) -> int:
        ceiling = ((taf_row[pd.Index(CLOUD_COVER)] == 'OVC') | (
            taf_row[pd.Index(CLOUD_COVER)] == 'BKN'))

        if ceiling.any():
            return np.nanmin(np.where(
                ceiling, taf_row[pd.Index(CLOUD_BASE)], np.nan)
            )
        return 2000

    def max_wind(taf_series: pd.Series) -> int:
        return np.max(taf_series[['WindSpeed', 'WindGust']])

    for index, current_line in taf.iterrows():
        # minimum_flight_category
        taf.loc[index, 'Category'] = criteria.loc[
            (current_line['Visibility'] >= criteria['visibility']) &
            (lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height(current_line) >= criteria['ceiling'])
        ].index.max()
   

        if index == 0:
            taf.loc[index, 'ChangeGroup'] = 'BECMG'
            continue
        # -------------------------------------------------------
        predominate_line = (
            taf.loc[taf.loc[:, 'ChangeGroup'] == 'BECMG']).iloc[-1, ]

        predom_max_speed = max_wind(predominate_line)

        current_max_speed = max_wind(current_line)

        becoming_conditions = [
            ((np.abs(predom_max_speed - current_max_speed) >= 10) |
                # NOTE Wind Direction: A change > 30 degrees when the predominant
                # wind speed or gusts are expected to be 15 knots or greater
                ((np.max([predom_max_speed, current_max_speed]) > 15) & (
                    np.abs(predominate_line['WindDirection'] -
                           current_line['WindDirection']) > 30))) |
            # if the flight category has crossed a threshold
            (taf.loc[index, 'Category'] != predominate_line['Category'])
        ]

        taf.loc[index, 'ChangeGroup'] = (
            np.where(becoming_conditions, 'BECMG', None))

    return taf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dev_mock(pd.DataFrame.from_records(MOCK_DATA))
```

Comment: I'm halfway through writing a suggestion but your category outputs have changed. They used to be all "E". Which is correct?

Comment: Uh yes sorry for the confusion, you are correct all the `MOCK_DATA` is cat E.  I'm working from a couple different environments.  The output of the update is from a different data source which I'll post as well.

Comment: Do your `ChangeGroup` columns in the input always start off as `None`?

Comment: Yes.  the purpose of the function is to determine and generate the change group.  There is another change group `TEMPO` that I have yet to really start working on.  A `TEMPO` condition is a condition which would only be expected to only occur for an intermittent amount of time and potentially several other factors.  After this function, rows with `ChangeGroup == None` get dropped. Values `df.fillna("")`  `df.astype(str)`  formatted to the terminal aerodrome forecast specification.  Then the entire dataframe is joined as a single string `row\nrow\n...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second data set is more useful for testing since it outputs different categories instead of all `E`.

I am ignoring all of your edited code and am comparing for equivalence based on your original solution: aside from your "edit 2" which has a spelling mistake; `funk` should be `func`.

In your `CRITERIA`, rename `index` to `category` directly in the literal dictionary so that you don't have to do it later with `rename_axis`.

Delete your `CLOUD_GROUP`.

Delete the backslash in your docstring for `dev_mock`.

Your two inner functions - `lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height` and `max_wind` - should not be inner since they don't have any closure references; they should be moved to the global scope.

`lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height` needs to be rephrased in a vectorised manner. The comparison to `OVC` and `BKN` should be performed using an `isin` call. Don't call `any`. Apply your two-dimensional boolean predicate to a slice of the dataframe replacing ignored values with `inf`, and then apply `min` on axis 1. Take the default of 2000 using `nan_to_num`.

Your `iterrows` probably can't be avoided due to a convoluted, recursive reliance on a changing `predominate_line` (which should be called `predominant_line`).

Your `becoming_conditions` should not be in a list literal, and your subsequent application of `np.where` is incorrect. This is difficult or impossible to vectorise, so revert to a basic Python `if`. The binary operators `|`, `&` should be replaced with Python logical operators `or`, `and` because you're dealing with scalars.

In your `becoming_conditions`, do not call `np.max` with a list literal, nor `np.abs`, because in both cases there are only two values to compare so you should just use the Python built-ins.

The category assignment can be expressed in a vectorised manner by doing a cross-join (cartesian product) of the `taf` and `criteria` dataframes; filtering where the minimum predicates are true; doing a group by the original index; and then taking the maximum of each group.

Your dataframe should be loaded such that the timestamps are parsed from strings to actual timestamps. I have not shown this in my suggested code.

Spelling: `ammendment` -> `amendment`.

You should not, on every loop iteration, repeat your search for the last `BECMG` row. This can be stored in a variable that updates whenever a new `BECMG` assignment is performed.

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

MOCK_DATA = [...]
MOCK_DATA2 = [...]

CRITERIA = {
    'ceiling': [2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100],
    'visibility': [4800, 3200, 3200, 1600, 800],
    'category': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
}
CLOUD_COVER = [
    'CloudCover1',
    'CloudCover2',
    'CloudCover3',
    'CloudCover4',
    'CloudCover5',
]
CLOUD_BASE = [
    'CloudBase1',
    'CloudBase2',
    'CloudBase3',
    'CloudBase4',
    'CloudBase5',
]


def lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height(taf: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    ceiling = taf[CLOUD_COVER].isin(('OVC', 'BKN'))

    # The cloud base types are screwed up and contain a bunch of None
    # that need to be coerced to floats.
    min_ceil = taf[CLOUD_BASE].astype(float).values
    min_ceil[~ceiling] = np.inf

    return np.nan_to_num(
        x=min_ceil.min(axis=1),
        posinf=2000,
    )


def get_category(taf: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    taf = taf.assign(Index=taf.index)
    criteria = pd.DataFrame(CRITERIA)
    ceil_choice = (
        taf[['Index', 'Ceiling', 'Visibility']]
        .join(other=criteria, how='cross')
    )
    return (
        ceil_choice[
            (ceil_choice.Visibility >= ceil_choice.visibility) &
            (ceil_choice.Ceiling >= ceil_choice.ceiling)
        ]
        .groupby('Index').category.max()
    )


def dev_mock(taf: pd.DataFrame):
    """
    applies the amendment & specification criteria
    """

    taf['Ceiling'] = lowest_bkn_or_ovc_height(taf)
    taf['Category'] = get_category(taf)
    taf['MaxWind'] = taf[['WindSpeed', 'WindGust']].max(axis=1)

    taf.loc[0, 'ChangeGroup'] = 'BECMG'
    predominant_line = taf.loc[0]

    for index, current_line in taf.iloc[1:, :].iterrows():
        becoming_conditions = (
            abs(
                predominant_line.MaxWind - current_line.MaxWind
            ) >= 10
            # Wind Direction: A change > 30 degrees when the predominant
            # wind speed or gusts are expected to be 15 knots or greater
            or (
                max(predominant_line.MaxWind, current_line.MaxWind) > 15
                and abs(
                    predominant_line.WindDirection - current_line.WindDirection
                ) > 30
            )
            # if the flight category has crossed a threshold
            or current_line.Category != predominant_line.Category
        )

        if becoming_conditions:
            predominant_line = current_line
            group = 'BECMG'
        else:
            group = None
        taf.loc[index, 'ChangeGroup'] = group

    return taf


def main() -> None:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(MOCK_DATA2)
    taf = dev_mock(df.copy())

    with StringIO() as f:
        taf.to_csv(f)
        print(f.getvalue())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks again for your input, it really helps me learn.   Tomorrow I’ll set aside some time and break down your solution.  You have a few methods that I haven’t really used before.